# OnItemClick never being called for button in ListView

Tags: android, listview, buttonclick, onitemclick

I'm trying to implement Onclicklistener for `button` inside `Listview` item but unable to get OnitemClick method called in listview.

I got the following code snippet from `stack overflow`

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
            // Your code for item clicks
            ( break point)               
            click++;
        }
    });
```

The break point never goes off when i click the button.

**Activity Code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

long click=0;
String[] aOrderID = {"1-AA-355433", "2-AA-456474", "3-AA-43546464", "4-A-446464E6","5-A-43555" };

String[] aOrderType = {
        "LIMIT-BUY",
        "LIMIT-SELL",
        "LIMIT-BUY",
        "LIMIT-SELL",
        "LIMIT-BUY"
};

double[] aPrice={3353.33, 4567.77, 335.66, 535.77, 678.67};
double[] aVOL={93353.33, 94567.77, 9335.66, 9535.77, 9678.67};

ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomListAdapter whatever = new CustomListAdapter(this,
            aOrderID, aOrderType,aPrice, aVOL );

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    listView.setAdapter(whatever);

    ////////////////////////
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
            // Your code for item clicks
   // CODE NEVER GETS HER AFTER BUTTON IS CLICKED ON                
   click++;
        }
    });
}

}
```

**CUSTOM ADAPTER**

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

int ted;
//to reference the Activity
private final Activity context;

//to store the animal images
private Integer[] imageIDarray = null;
//List of order ids
private String[] aOrderID = null;
// Type of order id limit buy
private String[] aOrderType = null;
// Price, price to sell of buy at
private double[] aPrice = null;
// Amount of bitcoins to buy or sell
private double[] aVol = null;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context,
                         String[] aOrderID, String[] aOrderType,
                         double[] aPrice, double[] aVol) {


    super(context, R.layout.row2, aOrderID);

    this.context = context;

    this.aOrderID = aOrderID;
    this.aOrderType = aOrderType;
    this.aPrice = aPrice;
    this.aVol = aVol;
}

public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null, true);


    TextView temp;
    temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idOrderID);
    temp.setText(aOrderType[position]);

    temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idOrderID);
    temp.setText(aOrderID[position]);

    temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idVol);
    temp.setText(Double.toString(aVol[position]));

    temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idPrice);
    temp.setText(Double.toString(aPrice[position]));

    return rowView;

}

}
```

**XML FOR LISTVIEW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView33"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ROW!"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView34"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ROW2"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView33" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView35"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="  Oder Type    "
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView33"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/IDtYPE"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy Limit Order"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView35"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView37"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="  Volume  "
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView34"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView35" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView40"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Type::"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idOrderID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Buy Limmit"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView40"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView43"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Price  "
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView40" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:text="Delete Order"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.501"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView34" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView45"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:text="-------------------------------------------------"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idPrice"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="000.00"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView43"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/idOrderID" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/idVol"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="2.9999"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView37"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView35" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use button click event from this method. Try this.

```
public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row2, null, true);


TextView temp;
temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idOrderID);
temp.setText(aOrderType[position]);

temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idOrderID);
temp.setText(aOrderID[position]);

temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idVol);
temp.setText(Double.toString(aVol[position]));

temp = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.idPrice);
temp.setText(Double.toString(aPrice[position]));

Button btn = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.button);
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //do your stuff.
        }
    });

return rowView;

}
```

Comment: To remove a item from the list box, wont I have to get the onclick event in my Activity class? How could I remove it from within the onCkick event inside the adapterclass?????

Comment: You should create interface between activity class & adaper class to make changes in activity class via adapter class.

Comment: Still learning java I dont know wht you mean by create interface between actity class and adapter class?